# Docx4j removing images when merging documents

Tags: docx4j

I have this piece of code that merges the main part of a "parent" doc with a "secondary" doc.

```
Document parentDoc = cmis.getFile(parentFilePath);
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackageParent = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(parentDoc.getContentStream().getStream());
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackageOriginal = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(originalFile.inputStream());
wordMLPackageParent.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(wordMLPackageOriginal.getMainDocumentPart().getContent());
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
wordMLPackageParent.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

Although the merge is performed correctly, all my images are lost in the resulting file:

[image]

Initially, I suspected that there might be an issue with the images in the original file. However, when I simply execute:

```
wordMLPackageOriginal.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

the resulting file has the correct images.
Why they are being lost on the merged file?

Comment: The images are being lost because your code does nothing to handle them (images are in their own Part, tied to the MainDocumentPart by a rels part).   In the general case, merging documents is tricky, so our commercial Docx4j Enterprise does it.  Otherwise, if your documents are simple and use the same styles, code which adds the images might suffice.